# angularjs - use variable from service to create a scope in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services

I'm trying to use a service to create a scope in my controller.

The service code is the following:

```
angular.module('GoogleMapsService', []).service('GoogleMaps', [
  '$cordovaGeolocation', '$ionicLoading', '$ionicPlatform', '$q', function($cordovaGeolocation, $ionicLoading, $ionicPlatform, $q) {
    var GoogleMaps, addMarkerOnMap, convertCoordinatesToFormattedAddress, getGPSCoordinatesFromDevice, initGoogleMap, mapDetails, useAddress, useGPSCoordinates;
    GoogleMaps = this;
    GoogleMaps.deferred = null;
    mapDetails = {
      lat: '',
      long: '',
      address: ''
    };
    getGPSCoordinatesFromDevice = function() {
      var coordinates, cordovaGPSModuleOptions;
      $ionicLoading.show({
        template: '<ion-spinner icon="bubbles"></ion-spinner><br/>Acquiring location!'
      });
      coordinates = {};
      cordovaGPSModuleOptions = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 0
      };
      return $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(cordovaGPSModuleOptions).then((function(position) {
        var lat, long;
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        long = position.coords.longitude;
        mapDetails.lat = lat;
        mapDetails.long = long;
        return coordinates = {
          lat: lat,
          lng: long
        };
      }));
    };
    convertCoordinatesToFormattedAddress = function(map, coordinates) {
      var geocoder;
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      return geocoder.geocode({
        location: coordinates
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          return mapDetails.address = results[0].formatted_address;
        } else {
          return console.log("unable to use reverse geocode to get formatted address for coordinates provided");
        }
      });
    };
    addMarkerOnMap = function(map, coordinates) {
      var marker;
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: coordinates,
        title: 'Location',
        draggable: true,
        infoWindow: {
          content: "<div><h3>Move me!</h3></div>"
        }
      });
      return marker;
    };
    initGoogleMap = function(coordinates) {
      var map;
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: coordinates,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      addMarkerOnMap(map, coordinates);
      convertCoordinatesToFormattedAddress(map, coordinates);
      return map;
    };
    useGPSCoordinates = function() {
      GoogleMaps.deferred = $q.defer();
      console.log(getGPSCoordinatesFromDevice().then(function(value) {
        var gpsCoordinates;
        gpsCoordinates = value;
        initGoogleMap(gpsCoordinates);
        return $ionicLoading.hide();
      }));
      return GoogleMaps.deferred.promise;
    };
    useAddress = function() {
      return console.log("using address");
    };
    return GoogleMaps = {
      'useGPS': useGPSCoordinates,
      'useAddress': useAddress,
      'mapDetails': mapDetails
    };
  }
]);
```

it returns and object called `GoogleMaps`.

From my controller, I call this service like the following:

```
$scope.evtClickUseGPSPosition = function() {
  var gpsConfirm;
  gpsConfirm = {
    modalClass: "modal-gps-confirm",
    modalMessage: 'We will try to detect your current position automatically using your device GPS. Be sure the GPS is enabled and, if asked, give the app permission to use GPS',
    confirmText: 'Locate'
  };
  return myModals.confirm(gpsConfirm, $scope).then(function(res) {
    if (res === true) {
      return GoogleMaps.useGPS();
    } else {
      return console.log("cancelled...");
    }
  });
};
```

and basically, when somebody clicks on a button, I display a modal asking for confirmation (the modal is another service I have), and on modal promise resolution, I call the service that creates the map.

Everything works, but I need to be able to create a scope called "address" with the resulting value from GoogleMaps-mapDetails.address, but this returns empty the first time I click, and not empty the second time.

I think it is related to the way the promises are resolved, but I cannot figure out how to solve this.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: i think the problem is that, mapDetails is empty until `GoogleMaps.useGPS()` is run in controller, when you confirm first time the function is run and sets mapDetails, and you can be able to see map details at second time

Comment: any idea or suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: you can create function in service which is sets only mapDetails and call that function when controller initialize

Comment: but then mapDetails will be empty, as it is populated with the right value when the other functions are called, or not?